# React+Typescript+Webpack4: Cannot find module '***.json'

Tags: webpack-4

I am trying to import the data from a .json file in a .tsx using following:

```
import data from "data/mockup.json"
```

but I got the error

> Cannot find module 'data/mockup.json'

My webpack config looks like this:

```
const babelLoader = {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
        cacheDirectory: true,
        presets: [
            ["@babel/preset-env", {
                "targets": {
                    "browsers": ["last 2 versions", "safari >= 7"]
                },
                "modules": true
            }]
        ]
    }
};

module.exports = {
    entry: {...},
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.json'],
        alias: {
            data: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app/data')
        }
    },
    output: {...},
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    babelLoader,
                    {
                        loader: 'ts-loader'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(dom7|swiper)\/).*/,
                use: [
                    babelLoader
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    ...
}
enter code here
```

I think the .json is built in webpack4 by default so there may be something wrong with my webpack config?

Version used:
webpack: v4.4.1
typescript: 2.7.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

declare module in d.ts file

```
declare module "*.json"
```

Add a field in tsconfig.json in compiler options

```
"typeRoots": [ "node_modules/@types", "./typings.d.ts" ],
```

Now import into file (.tsx)

```
import * as data from "./dat/data.json";
```

> Webpack@4.4.1 and Typescript@2.7.2

Hope this helps!!!

Ref1: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html

Ref2: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter/issues/12

Comment: you can find  the code base for quick start : https://github.com/HariDongli/react-typeScript-webpack.git

Comment: Starting with TypeScript 2.9 you can `import data from "./dat/data.json";` directly see `--resolveJsonModule` https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: THANK YOU - In all my searchings I hadn't run across the "declare module "*.json"
" trick, and then typeRoots -- works like a charm!  Allows me to have my json files in a separate package in my monorepo, export the individual files as named modules and import them in my root application!

Answer (score 2):

Although answers are helpful to load the JSON file as a module, they are limited in many aspects

- First: the typescript can load by default JSON files, you only need to add into `tsconfig.json` below line:

  ```
   {
      ...

      "resolveJsonModule": true,

      ...
   }
  ```
- second: the suggested solution will enable implicitly for type check and auto-completion

[image]

**P.S. the attached image is from a tutorial that talks about the same subject click [here](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/importing-json-modules-in-typescript) to check more**

Answer (score 2):

Personnaly, uncommenting :

```
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true   /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */,
```

in the file `tsconfig.json` did the trick.

I found the hint [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2018/05/07/using-typescript-with-react-native).